# Where do deviance residuals come from?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, poisson-regression, deviance

I'm trying to understand deviance and deviance residuals using a simple Poisson regression model as an example. Let's say we have a response variable
$$ y_i \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda_i)$$
and we assume
$$ \lambda_i = \exp(a + b x_i) $$

```
## generate random data
y <- rpois(25, 2)
x <- rnorm(25) + (log(replace(y, y == 0, 0.25)))
```

We can estimate $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ by maximising the log-likelihood function
$$ \ell(a,b) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ y_i (a+bx_i) - \exp(a+bx_i) - \log(y_i!) \right ]$$

```
mod1 <- optim(c(1, 1), function(p)
    with(list(mu=p[1] + p[2] * x), -sum(y * mu - exp(mu))))

mod2 <- glm(y ~ x, family='poisson', data=data.frame(y=y, x=x))

## check that the parameters coincide
mod1$par
coefficients(mod2)
```

Now, we can rewrite the log-likelihood function in terms of $\lambda$ $$
\ell(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ y_i \lambda_i - \exp(\lambda_i) -
\log(y_i!) \right ]$$ The log-likelihood of the model is $\ell(\hat\lambda)$
where $\hat\lambda=\exp(\hat a + \hat b x)$.

```
## eta = a + bx
eta <- cbind(1, x) %*% mod1$par
tail(eta)
tail(predict(mod2))

## yhat = exp(eta)
yhat <- exp(eta)
tail(yhat)
tail(fitted.values(mod2))

## log-likelihood
sum(dpois(y, yhat, log=TRUE))
logLik(mod2)[1]
```

On the other hand, the log-likelihood of the "saturated" model is $\ell(\hat\lambda_s)$ where $\hat\lambda_s=y$. The deviance of the model (the so-called "residual deviance") is 
$$D=2\left[\ell(\hat\lambda_s)-\ell(\hat\lambda)\right]$$
in other words it's two times the difference between the likelihood of the saturated and the likelihood of the model.

```
## deviance: D = 2(logLik_fullmodel - logLik_model)
2 * (sum(dpois(y, y, log=TRUE)) - sum(dpois(y, yhat, log=TRUE)))
mod2$deviance
```

Now is when I get lost. I know that
$$d^2=2\left[ \hat y - \hat y_s - y (\log\hat\lambda-\log\hat\lambda_s) \right]$$
are the squared "deviance residuals" and it turns out that $\sum_i d^2_i$
equals the residual deviance.

```
tail(2 * (yhat - y - y * (eta - log(y))))
tail(resid(mod2)^2)
sum(resid(mod2)^2)
```

However I'm at a loss where this equation comes from. Can somebody shed light on this?

### Edit

Based on the fact that $\sum d^2 = D$ I worked out that
$$d^2_i = 2 \left[ \ell_i(\hat\lambda_s) - \ell_i(\hat\lambda) \right] $$
So basically $\ell_i(\hat\lambda_s)$ and $\ell_i(\hat\lambda)$ are two estimates of $\log\Pr(y_i)$. Visually, suppose $y_i=2$, then these 2 estimates are the 2 bars corresponding to "y=2" in the plot below

```
barplot(rbind(dpois(0:4, y[1], log=TRUE),
              dpois(0:4, yhat[1], log=TRUE)),
        beside=TRUE, names.arg=paste0('y=', 0:4),
        legend.text=c('saturated', 'model'), args.legend=list(x='bottom'))
```

[image]

However given that $\ell_i(\hat\lambda_s) - \ell_i(\hat\lambda) \geq 0$ I still don't know where the sign of $d_i$ comes from.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer in *Modern Applied Statistics with S* by W.N. Venables and B.D. Ripley, p.189:

> The deviance residuals $d_i$ are defined as the signed square roots of
>   the summands of the deviance (7.5) taking the same sign as $y_i - \hat\mu_i$.